# What is the Maven dependency for javax.servlet-api 3.1 implementation?

Tags: java, maven, servlets, servlet-3.0

I'm using javax.servlet-api-3.1 version in my project. But as this is just an API specification I require an implementation jar. Please let me know the appropriate maven dependency for it.

Note: Please note i'm using embedded jetty as my servlet container.

[Update]

Following is my API dependency and I'm looking for the implementation dependency.

```
      <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Don't need  implementation dependency in maven,You should show us error

Answer (score 1):

The implementation of the Servlet API is Jetty itself. I believe that Jetty 9 supports that API.

Answer (score 1):

The reference implementation is of course Glassfish from Oracle! But you can use Tomcat or Jetty or the servlet container that you use. For glassfish, maven central has it at:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.servlet</artifactId>
  <version>3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

But you normally do not need it, because the API is all that is needed for compilation, and for tests you normally use mocks. You really should explain *why* you need an implementation.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with org.glassfish implementation of java.servlet aip.  The java.servlet.ServletOutputStream class does not implement all of the methods in the 3.1 spec. For example isReady() is not implemented by the glass fish implementation.